# What Mechanisum does Windows 10 use to Detect simularities in programs to Group Them on the TaskBar

Tags: windows, taskbar

Windows 10, groups running windows of a program under a single Icon on the TaskBar.  But will also group windows of Similar Programs. I'm trying to find out what its key-ing on in the binary/window to do this (and prevent it).

This gets even more confusing because when some Installers get done, and leave a Open Notepad.exe Logfile; it does not group up with my other running notpad.exe windows and is all by it's self.

From Testing I know that it Doesn't use

- CRC or other comparisons
- Binary location
- Binary File Size
- Binary File Dates
- Binary File Name
- Binary Product Version
- Binary Product Name
- Binary Copyright
- Binary File Version
- Binary Product version
- Binary Original File name
- Binary File Description
- Binary Icon
- Window Title
- Window Icon
- etc (there was more done but I don't recall everything I've tried, and I don't want to incorrectly put something down if I'm not sure)

This was all Tested by editing a complied Binary (same as I did win win7 and XP before that), To specifically make Visually distinct running copies for SAS applications.

I did this alot back in Win7, and I think it was just the Binaries Icon that was key. Not so in Win10.

Here is the Properties of three different Binaries, in different locations, that will all go under one Icon on the Task bar. The Actual Icon used on the task bar is from whatever binary was started first.

[image: Three File Properties]

Comment: https://superuser.com/ is a better forum for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while SuperUser cover more general questions.

Comment: That was a thought, but as I'm editing Binaries (akin to binary programing) and that the answer is more useful to a programing crowd than a user base I ended up going for here first. For instance a .net programmer might want his two programs to act as one (by default) in the windows task bar. An answer here would help that.